# Shouldn't I be able to initialize a parameter list like I can a set of values?

Tags: scala

Scala already supports this:

```
val (a : Int, b: String, c: Double) = {
  val someInt : Int = 42 // ... complex computations ...
  val someString : String = "42" // ... complex computations ...
  val someDouble : Double = 42.0D // ... complex computations ...
  (someInt, someString, someDouble)
}
```

I was surprised when I couldn't do this:

```
class Foo(a : Int, b: String, c: Double) {
  def this(tuple: (Int, String, Double)) = {
    this {
      val someInt : Int = 42 // ... complex computations ...
      val someString : String = "42" // ... complex computations ...
      val someDouble : Double = 42.0D // ... complex computations ...
      (someInt, someString, someDouble)
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler yields this:

```
Error:(3, 6) called constructor's definition must precede calling
             constructor's definition
this {
^
```

It seems natural to me to think of a arguments to a constructor as a tuple, but perhaps that's just me. I realize that I can accomplish a similar thing using 
the companion object but that places the logic outside of the class itself.

Do you know a way to place the "complex computations" in a non-primary constructor without using the companion object?

Comment: You're receiving a tuple, yet discarding it's values completely, only to create other non-related values which you return?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Which also looks like a recursive call to the same constructor

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Yes, you're right, that code makes a recursive call to the constructor which is clearly and rightly not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do with

```
val (a : Int, b: String, c: Double) = someComputation
```

is, computing a value on the right side of the equal sign, and assign it to the name(s) on the left side of the equal sign.

What you do in the second example is

```
class Foo(a : Int, b: String, c: Double) {
```

you create a class with a default constructor taking three single parameters. If you like to think of it as a tuple or not, it simply *is* a parameter list with three single parameters.

Then with

```
def this(tuple: (Int, String, Double)) =
```

you try to define another constructor taking *one* parameter named "tuple" of type 3-tuple.

BUT

When you write something like this

```
def someName( aParam: TheType ) = { computation }
```

you *declare* a named function/method and its parameter list, then to the right of the equal sign you define its *implementation*.

The equal sign now is a marker, that the computation will not be without result, but indeed the result of the computation will be the result of the whole function/method.

So, you somehow may have to think in the other direction. The parameters flowing in from the *left* of the equal sign lead to a result to the *right* of the equal sign, where this "lead to" is defined by the computation.

One thing more: You can -and sometimes must- also leave off the equal sign:

```
def someMethod { someSideEffect }
```

This defines a method where nothing is returned.

At least until Scala 2.11, a constructor is of the last sort: It has no equal sign, as it does not return a value. Much more, as a side effect, it initialises the object under construction.
That is, space for the object is allocated, and this space is initialised by executing the constructor's implementation with the given parameters.

So, coming back to your second example, with

```
def this(tuple: (Int, String, Double))
```

what you do is, *declaring* a *constructor* (an implementation to initialise an object under construction) taking *one* parameter named "tuple".

Now, in the code block following the declaration, you should define how to use the given tuple to initialise the object.

But what you do instead is

```
this {
  val someInt : Int = 42 // ... complex computations ...
  val someString : String = "42" // ... complex computations ...
  val someDouble : Double = 42.0D // ... complex computations ...
  (someInt, someString, someDouble)
}
```

i.e, you *call* the exactly same constructor with a value computed inside its implementation definition.

So, when this constructor is called with a tuple, you define that it should forget this tuple, but instead call that same constructor with another, computed, tuple, but by calling it, this newly created tuple will be forgotten, just to call that constructor with another, computed, tuple, but by calling it .....

This is confusing to the Scala-ist as well to the compiler. It does not know what indeed should happen when with what computations any more (and why ...).
You declared something like a hen-and-egg problem to the compiler.

So tl;dr :  NO.

The first example assigns values computed from the right side of '=' to the name(s) on the left side.

The second example defines a recursive constructor implementation, what simply is not possible in Scala.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.